# Grails additional columns in table or list

Tags: grails, model, dns, grails-orm

I'm trying for several days to receive a list from my Data. The Domain looks like this:

```
class Alpha {    
    String a
    String b
    etc.
    static hasMany = [beta:Beta]

}

class Beta {
    String a
    Integer foo
    String status
    static belongsTo = [alpha:Alpha]
    static constraints = {
        status(nullable:false, inList:["val1","val2","val3", "val4"])
    }
}
```

I'd like to have in Alpha the sum of all Beta.foo and of all Beta.foo in a certain status. Best would be something like an additional row ( `Integer sumVal1 ...` ).

I tried named queries:

```
static namedQueries = {
        erledigterProbeAufwend {
            createAlias ('Beta', 'b')
            eq ('b.status', 'val1')
            projections {
                groupProperty('b.alpha')
                sum('b.foo', 'sumFooVal1')
            }
        }
}
```

But this just give me one sum at a time.

I'm looking forward to get some help on that.

Greetings
Bas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be calculated [formula field](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties), but with a [subquery trick](http://www.pubbs.net/201003/grails/37677-re-grails-user-derived-properties-in-grails-13-and-using-hql-or-sql-and-what-is-the-proper-format.html):

```
static mapping = {
    betaCount formula: "(SELECT count(*) FROM Beta b WHERE b.alpha_id = id and b.status in('a', 'b'))"
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! I'd like to publish my case, as another example: 
`totalFilhos formula: '(SELECT count(*) FROM atendimento a WHERE a.atendimento_pai = cod_atendimento)'`

Comment: and what if you want not a `count (*)`, but all lines, with the same trick?

Comment: In one field, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Create transient variables in your Alpha class and populate them in an onLoad event.

```
class Alpha {    
    String a
    String b
    etc.
    static transients = ["sumVal1",...]
    static hasMany = [beta:Beta]

    def onLoad = {
       sumVal1 = ....
    }    

}
```

Comment: I doubt it's better then having in Alpha: `def getVal1() { beta.findAll{it.status in ['a', 'b']}.sum() }` and querying it lazily. When retrieving a.beta it will run additional query anyway.